# Drupal 7 initalising salesforce REST API service from "Salesforce suite"

Tags: drupal-7, salesforce

Since I am not experienced with Drupal, i have ran into a small issue trying to call web services from a salesforce REST API. Based on an example for Drupal 8 i have the following code

```
$client = \Drupal::service('salesforce.client');
```

If i try the given example on Drupal 7 I get the following error:

> Class 'Drupal' not found in ..."

I am wondering what the alternative for Drupal 7 is.

Comment: The module "Service" is part of Drupal8 core. See https://www.drupal.org/project/services for Drupal 7.

Comment: @Syscall Thank you, this can be marked as resolved

Comment: You're welcome. You can create an answer and mark it as solved. Or I can make one if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The module "Service" is part of Drupal8 core. See
>   drupal.org/project/services for Drupal 7.

Answered by @Syscall